# Using the wildcard attribute selector in CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is it possible to use wildcard to select data attribute by name with CSS only?

```
[data-widget-type="*.color"] {
    color: orange
}

<ul>
    <li>asdasd</li>
    <li data-widget-type="red.color">asdasd</li>
    <li data-widget-type="none.color">asdasd</li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Are you asking how to select attrs where `color` appears anywhere, or only attrs where `color` is at the end? E.g., Red Devil's answer is for the former, mine is for the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, just not quite the way you've done it. You need to move the delimiter (in your case, the "wildcard" asterisk) outside of your string declaration. There's also a better delimiter for what it looks like you're trying to select. Here's the right [`attr` selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

```css
li[data-widget-type$="color"] {
    color: orange;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>asdasd</li>
    <li data-widget-type="red.color">asdasd</li>
    <li data-widget-type="none.color">asdasd</li>
</ul>
```

This will select all the `li` elements with `data-widget-type` values that end in `color`, and change their color to orange.

Here's a [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2agqn1r2/) to play around with it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

```css
[data-widget-type*="color"] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>asdasd</li>
    <li data-widget-type="red.color">asdasd</li>
    <li data-widget-type="none.color">asdasd</li>
</ul>
```

More info about Attribute selectors - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Answer (score 1):

```
    li[data-widget-type$=".color"] { 
        color: orange;
    }

<ul>
    <li>asdasd</li>
    <li data-widget-type="red.color">asdasd</li>
    <li data-widget-type="none.color">asdasd</li>
</ul>
```

You can use css selectors for that too.

For specific atribute you can use `[]` and if you are comparing something in css and want to search at the beginning `^=` or if you want to find it at the end `$=` you can use this.

Also if you don't know where the word is in the comparing word then you can use wildcard `*` too. So in our case it is `li[data-widget-type*=".col"]`

As an advice, I like to struct my css files like this.
I always have a css class for colors.

```
li[class*="red"] { 
    color: red;
}
```

So I can also reach it from any other class like `any-red`, `new-red` when I don't want to use single `red` class.

Also don't forget that you can also use `li[data-widget-type|="red"]` for elements that starting with red. This is an old but good move from CSS2, some browsers may reject it so take care.

So here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52fw826b/) and here is the snippet.

```css
li[data-widget-type$=".color"] { 
    color: orange;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>asdasd</li>
    <li data-widget-type="red.color">asdasd</li>
    <li data-widget-type="none.color">asdasd</li>
</ul>
```